# Kubectl error You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized) when using kubectl

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I proceeded with the work referring to the following site
(I don't use EKS.I create k8s on ec2 using kops)

[Getting Started with kOps on AWS](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/getting_started/aws/)

When I tried to call `kubectl get service` I got the message: `error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)`

Here is what I did:

1. Setup IAM user(create user and add role)
2. Cluster State storage(S3)
3. Prepare local environment

```
export NAME=myfirstcluster.example.com 
export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://prefix-example-com-state-store
```

4. Create cluster configuration `kops create cluster--zones=us-west-2a${NAME}`
5. Build the Cluster `kops update cluster ${NAME} --yes`

★success★

6. When I try to access the cluster e.g. `kubectl get nodes`, I keep receiving error: `You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)`

Any idea how to fix this issue?

I tried some other way.

1. attach instance profile to EC2
2. delete `.kube/cache`
3. `kubectl apply -f aws-auth.yaml`

```
    apiVersion: v1 kind: ConfigMap metadata: name: aws-auth namespace: kube-system data: mapUsers: | - userarn: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:user/xxx username: xxx groups: - system:masters mapRoles: | - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:role/xxx username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}} groups: - system:bootstrappers - system:nodes
```

Same error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials).

4. Modify `.kube/config` users:

```
    name: xxclusterNAMExxx user: exec: apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1 command: aws-iam-authenticator args: - "token" - "-i" - "xxclusterNAMExxx" env: - name: AWS_PROFILE value: "xxxx"
```

All failed.

Comment: I discover same question.(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341494/kops-1-19-reports-error-unauthorized-when-interfacing-with-aws-cluster)

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
kops export kubecfg --admin
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following command

```sh
$ kops export kubecfg --admin --kubeconfig ~/workspace/kubeconfig --state=s3://YOUR-S3-BUCKET-NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/releases/1.19-notes/#changes-to-kubernetes-config-export

Yes you need to pass the users as well.

kops export kubecfg --name  --admin